# unable to hide filename in the URL using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, requestdispatcher

I am developing a web application and right now I am trying to **"hide"** the file name in the URL.

It is currently like that:

> /localhost/test/faculty_searchstudents.jsp

I want to hide the file name. I have tried using requestdispatcher like that:

```
  while (resultSet.next()) {
      String first_name = resultSet.getString("firstname");
      String last_name = resultSet.getString("lastname");
      String email = resultSet.getString("email");

      Object[] student = {first_name,last_name,email};
      studentList.add(student);
  }
  session.setAttribute("studentObject",studentList);
  RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getRequestDispatcher("faculty_searchstudents.jsp");
  dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

However when I run this code, it says that

> "The method getRequestDispatcher(String) is undefined ".

I already import it at the top of the file like this :

```
  <%@page import = "javax.servlet.*" %>
```

How do I hide the filename in the URL?

Comment: you can do as request.getRequestDispatcher("faculty_searchstudents.jsp")

Comment: Hi, i  have tried that, it kinda works but now it displays a blank webpage; My session.getAttribute("studentObject",studentList) is not displayed :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 RequestDispatcher dispatcher =getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("faculty_searchstudents.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("faculty_searchstudents.jsp");
```